# How can I get the VPN address into the openvpn --up script?

Tags: iptables, routing, openvpn

I'm using `openvpn` to connect to a third party VPN service.  The VPN provider has a pool of servers, and I don't know which one I'm going to get before I connect, and therefore what my IP address is going to be.  After connecting, I want to add the VPN address to an `iptables` rule.  I'm attempting to do this using the `openvpn --up cmd` option.

I've added the following to `client.conf`:

```
script-security 2
up /etc/openvpn/up.sh
```

`up.sh` looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash

# wait a bit
/bin/sleep 5

# get IP address from an external web server
VPN_IP=`/usr/bin/curl https://audiomason.com/ip/`

iptables -A OUTPUT --protocol tcp --destination $VPN_IP --jump ACCEPT
```

The `VPN_IP` variable is set correctly when I run `up.sh` manually, after starting `openvpn`.  When the script is triggered by `openvpn --up` during the startup process, the variable is set to my ISP assigned address.  I've also tried triggering the script with `--route-up` rather than `--up`, but this causes `curl` to time out.  It seems like the routing tables haven't fully been set up when the script is triggered.

Is there a way to get the VPN address into the `openvpn --up` script?

Comment: Maybe you need to wait longer and start the script in a separate process, so that OpenVPN has set up routes. I hope you also have a corresponding script to remove the rule when connection ends.

Comment: I tried setting the sleep time to 120, and got the same results.

Comment: In that case you might need to run the script in a background process, so that OpenVPN can continue performing rest of the connection initialization.

Comment: Any ideas on how to do that? Ultimately, I want to invoke openvpn as a systemd process.  The script  works when I do this: `systemctl start openvpn && ./up.sh`.

Comment: Google for "linux background process execution", and you should find information on it.